# Heat and molecular motion

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I have often read that heat is nothing more than the motion of molecules.  For instance, according to a NASA document on a Caltech website, "the hotter an object is, the faster the motion of the molecules inside it."  But what I want to know is: do the bouncing molecules *cause* heat, or is the motion of molecules *caused by* heat?  This sounds like a chicken-and-egg problem: which comes first?  There must be a better way of conceptualizing this.

Can you clarify it?

Comment: Ask yourself: What kind of world would it be without molecules (tiny things) moving randomly? I mean how can you imagine anything in nature assuming that matter is made up  of very small things but without those little things moving randomly?

Comment: You're talking about temperature. Not heat.

Answer (score 1):

Molecules are in constant motion and so they possess kinetic energy.
Molecules at a higher temperature have more kinetic energy i.e. they move faster.
You only observe the transfer of heat when two bodies at different temperature are put in thermal contact.

If a body at a higher temperature is put in thermal contact with a body at a lower temperature  then as the molecules interact (collide with one another) on average the molecules which had more kinetic energy (body at a higher temperature) would transfer some of their kinetic energy to the molecules which had less kinetic energy (body at a lower temperature).
This transfer of kinetic energy between a bodies at different temperatures we call heat.
Heat is that form of energy which is transferred from a hot body to a colder body.

If the two sets of molecules (bodies) are left alone then eventually on average all the molecules will have the same kinetic energy, the bodies will be at the same temperature and there will be no further transfer of heat between the bodies.

---

**Update**

You can supply energy to a body in a lot of ways other than heating it.
You can shine light or other types of waves on it, you can rub it, you can hit it, you can pass an electric current through it, etc.
This will give the molecules some kinetic energy.
That kinetic energy is distributed amongst the molecules.
In a solid the molecules will vibrate about a mean position whilst in a liquid and gas the molecules will also be able to undertake translational motion.

If you have a body at very low temperature then just shaking it can give the molecules extra kinetic energy with the temperature of the body rising.

Comment: But what I am asking is, why are molecules in constant motion in the first place?  What is it that gives them kinetic energy?  If, as you say, heat is the transfer of kinetic energy, then what if you have a single body which is not transferring kinetic energy anywhere?  Then there wouldn't be any heat, because there is no transfer?  That body would still have a temperature, wouldn't it?  What is the cause, and what is the effect?

Comment: @SumwunYumaynotno in response to your comment I have added a little more to my answer.

Comment: Not only are the molecules vibrating around, but they also have attractive forces (chemical bonds) between them to keep them stuck together.  These are competing in some sense. A Solid object is one in which the chemical bonds are stronger than the amount of vibration (heat), so they object stays stuck together despite the vibrations.  A Gas, on the other hand, has so much vibration that the molecules won't stay connected.  This applet shows this nicely; Try 1K, 50K, 500K and 1000K https://www.chm.davidson.edu/vce/MD/MD-Temperature.html

Comment: Another source that originates heat is chemical reactions - for example, fire releases "heat", as Oxygen oxidized some material and goes to a lower energy bond-state, the excess energy is released as "heat" - the resulting olecules vibrate much more strongly than the originals.

Answer (score 0):

Heat is a derived property which supervenes on the motion of molecules.

Molecules can move with or without heat.  The concept of heat is not necessary for molecular motion.  For example, we can vibrate molecules using sound wave.  If we know something about the motion of those molecules, we can even use them to do work.

However, due to many different effects, we often lose track of the motion of the molecules.  For example, in gas clouds, there are so many collisions and they are so unpredictable that it is *very* difficult to track any one given gas molecule, much less all of them.

The solution is that we model them statistically.  We say "here's the distribution of positions and velocities we expect from all of these molecules.  We don't really know where they are, but we expect them to be well described by this distribution."

Using this statistical approach, we define "heat."  Temperature is a measure derived from the statistical distribution of the velocities of the particles being measured.

In thermodynamics we use "heat" as a powerful tool for predicting what will happen.  When you have trillions or quadrillions of atoms whose velocity all comes from a reasonable distribution, the sum effect of all of them is *very* predictable thanks to the Central Limit Theorem.

In theory, if you knew how all of those molecules were vibrating, you could get more work out of them than you can get out of them if you only know their statistical distributions.  However, you will find that if you use a thermodynamic process to do this measurements, you will burn more work measuring than you can gain from that information.  And, it turns out, most every process you or I think of is a thermodynamic process.  There are a few processes which are "reversible" which don't have this flaw, but they have their own issues (which are more complicated and out of scope of this question)