# How do we know that temperature is the random motion of particles of matter?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

It is written in many textbooks that heat is the random motion of particles but no text book mentions that how do we know that heat is the random motion of particles

Comment: I don't believe this assertion. Please research more.

Comment: I think you mean temperature, not heat, but it's a good question.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of a previous one ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299161/heat-and-molecular-motion?rq=1 ). If you do not find useful the answers, you may recast your question explaining why you do not find them satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically the first field of theoretical physics based on the concept that heat is motion of molecules is [kinetic theory of gases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases)

The predecessor of the kinetic theory was [caloric theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caloric_theory)

According to the wikipedia article in 1857 Rudolf Clausius developed a theory that included rotational and vibrational modes of molecules as repositories of energy.

As I understand it, for decades the general scientific opinion was that definitive proof of the kinetic theory of gases was still lacking.

As I understand it, the kinetic theory of heat was regarded as plausible, but not proven beyond reasonable doubt.

Einstein's 1905 work in the field of thermodynamics changed that.   Einstein's work in thermodynamics:
- His doctoral thesis on diffusion of sugar molecules in water.
- His paper on brownian motion.

Einstein showed that it was possible to determine Avogadro's number from specific properties of diffusion and brownian motion.

Answer (score 0):

One historical answer is *Brownian Motion*, discovered by botanist Robert Brown and theoretically explained by Albert Einstein to be caused by random motion of particles due to heat:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion

Comment: Heat is NOT a property of a system but it is just a possible way   the internal energy is changed. Temperature in some cases can be proportional to the average kinetic energy of the microscopic motion, i.e. to the temperature. However, this is not the case of Brownian motion. Brownian trajectories are nowhere differentiable, so there is no direct kinetic energy associable to the movement of Brownian particles. The Brownian motion is only an indirect proof that there is an (invisible) motion at atomic level.

Comment: @GiorgioP yes, Brownian motion is indirect proof, I agree. But the conclusion that it comes from atomic movements is shown by Einstein, because he theoretically showed that this assumption leads to the correct statistics of Brownian motion (doesn’t it?) . And movement on atomic level means kinetic energy on atomic level, which consequently should be interpreted as heat. I think...

Comment: I believe that is the key to the question "how do we *know*..." - the mathematical theory based on the idea of random motion appears to correctly predict physical experiments/results, so presumably random motion is actually how it works (even though invisible).